# How to load the data in mdbCharts after the api call?

Tags: angular, charts

I am using mdbChart to load the PieGraph. I need to load the data after I do the API call. But it's showing an error.

My code is:

```
public chartType: string = 'pie';
public chartDatasets: Array<PieChart> = new Array<PieChart>();
public chartLabels: Array<String> = [];

getPieChartData() {
    let element: PieChart = {data: [], label: ""};
    this.dashboard.getUniqueProductUsers().subscribe(data => {
      let chartValue: Array<number> = new Array();
      for(let uniqueProductUser of data.uniqueProductUser) {
        let obj: any = { ...uniqueProductUser };
        this.chartLabels.push(uniqueProductUser.product_type_info);
        chartValue.push(parseInt(obj.userscount))
      }
      element.data = chartValue;
      element.label = "Product Traffic";
      this.chartDatasets.push(element);
      console.log(this.chartDatasets);
    })
  }
```

Interface is :

```
export interface PieChart {
  data: Array<number> ;
  label: String;
}
```

And HTML code is as:

```
<canvas mdbChart
            [chartType]="chartType"
            [datasets]="chartDatasets"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [colors]="chartColors"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [legend]="true">
        </canvas>
```

I am able to understand before I pushing data to the array is getting loaded. That's why I am getting configuration errors. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't load the chart until you have chartDatasets ready:

```
<canvas mdbChart *ngIf="chartDatasets.length"
            [chartType]="chartType"
            [datasets]="chartDatasets"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [colors]="chartColors"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [legend]="true">
        </canvas>
```